# Making a ruler functionality within the app, but different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm working on a project which particularly in this ViewController, I have set up a scale as a UIImageView and it needs to react on touch events based on that scale and to produce some output. However, my question is, how to implement accuracy for all of the different devices? I was thinking to try with if else statements for every single device (iPhone 4,5,6) and assign the properties based on those conditions. But that would be like dirty coding, or no? Is there any other method for this type of functionality? I need you to give me some opinions or tips just to put me on the right track. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIScreen`'s scale property to determine if the device has a retina screen (@2x or @3x), which will help to some extent. At present, every iPhone has the same number of points per inch (163), with differing numbers of pixels per inch depending on the device. The iPads are a different matter, though, as the iPad Mini has the same point density as an iPhone, but the 9.7" iPad and the iPad Pro have a lower density. I think for the iPads you'll need to detect the specific device to be able to figure out the physical screen size.